# Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'DBNull' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbnull

I trying to check for `DBNull` value in my `DataGridView` on cellvaluechanged event. 
Here's my code,

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    Try
        If IsDBNull(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value()) Or _
              Val(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) < 0 Then
         Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 0
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In my code i am trying to check that if that cell is empty or less than 0 than replace it with 0. But that doesn't seems to work and throws an exception `Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'DBNull'`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: using `OrElse` after the IsDBNull text will prevent the second evaluation from taking place if the first fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
If IsDBNull(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value()) Then
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 0
Else 
    If Val(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) < 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 0
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You are duplicating a line of code, using OrElse would prevent that.

Comment: @the_lotus .. thanks, yes you're right it's so not efficient .. that's only my bad habbit ..